# plt fill an area between two hlines with skewed lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if and how it would be possible to fill the area between two horizontal lines in pyplot. However, not with a color, but with multiple lines (I even drew a picture to show you what I mean)

[image]

Here is my code so far if you need it:

```py
g = plt.figure(i)
plt.plot(x_arr, pv_arr, zorder=100, color='firebrick')
plt.ylim([ymin, ymax])
plt.xlim([0, 60])
plt.hlines(pv_mean+pv_std_dv, xmin=-1, xmax=61)
plt.hlines(pv_mean-pv_std_dv, xmin=-1, xmax=61)
```

Comment: Do you mean [hatching](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_demo.html)?

Comment: yes exactly, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
x = np.linspace(0, 60, 500)
y = np.sin(x/5)
plt.plot(x, y, color='firebrick')
plt.xlim(0, 60)
plt.hlines([-.5, .5], 0, 60)
plt.fill_between([0, 60], [.5, .5], [-.5, -.5], hatch='/', facecolor='w')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes exactly! Perfect